# How to make a 2 line heading with GitHub Markdown?

Tags: markdown, line-breaks, multiline, github-flavored-markdown

I want to know how to make a markdown heading over 2 lines.

I tried using 2 headers, but that displays 2 headers rather than 1 multiline heading. For example,

```
# :emoji:
# Heading
```

displays,

## :emoji:

## Heading

Answer (score -1):

You can break any line in GitHub Markdown with the `<br>` element. This also applies to headers. Hence, the following can be done:

```
# :emoji:<br>Heading
```

## :emoji:
Heading

Notice how the line break is closer; GitHub will not add the heading underline between lines.